# byte array Dump data print as string python

Tags: php, python, printing, dump

this code work with socket python

this is print to my array

```
'\x00M2\x10\x00\x00\xa8\x00\x00\x1c\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\xfe\x00\x05\x00\x00\t\x>>00\x06\x00\x00\t\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x08\xfe\xff\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\t\x02\x01

  data d = bytearray(s.recv(1024))
```

How to print or dump data as string?

Comment: what type is data?

Comment: Your bytes sequence seems to be incorrect. it has `\x>>` which is invalid. Also it is missing the closing quote.`s.recv` returns *bytes*. Why converting to *bytearray*? and don't simply print that? What's the expected *print* output, as the data contains mainly unprintable *char*s?